# Number of different records (rows) in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

quite often I have to count then number of different records in a table. However, in MySQL neither

```
select count(distinct *) from t;
```

nor

```
select count(distinct t.*) from t;
```

work. I know that I can work around that by

```
select count(*) as countdistinctrows
from (
  select distinct * from t
) x;
```

but this is ugly. Is there really no way do ask for the number of distinct rows? By the way,

```
select distinct count(*) from t;
```

is not the answer since then distinct is applied to the number of rows in the table and thus gives the same as

```
select count(*) from t;
```

Comment: `Distinct *` is an oxymoron

Comment: Of course a question comes to mind: Why do have duplicate rows in a Relational table? Is there no Primary Key? The "ugly workaround" is the best way to get your count.

Comment: @dnoeth: sure, one would like to not have duplicate rows. But in my scenario it's not hat simple. I create a table from data where e.g. col 1 is supposed to to be a string indicating a category. But in the source data it can be "category1" or "category 1". I use mysql with regexp_replace to clean the mess. And afterwards I'd like to know if I still have only distinct rows.

Comment: So this table is in staging area, then go with the `count from (select distinct)`, there's no better/easier way.

Comment: @dnoeth Okay, that is certainly not what I was hoping for. But is there a reason why `select count(distinct t.*) from t;` is illegal in (My)SQL? I can't see why it would harm to have it, giving that `select count(distinct col1, col2...) from t` still works.

Comment: It's illegal in every relational DBMS as every table needs a Primary Key effectively disallowing dulicate rows :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use this:

```
select count(*) as countdistinctrows
from (
  select distinct * from t
) x;
```

the only alternative I can think of is to specify all the column names manually:

```
select count(distinct id, col1, col2, col3, ...)
from t;
```

Comment: Well, that is not really an option as I have sometimes fifty or more columns in a table.

Comment: @diffset there's really no other way, you can use a count(*) from a subquery or a count(distinct columns....)